# How to run POData-Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, odata

I'm new to laravel and I tried to run POData (https://github.com/Algo-Web/POData-Laravel). For that I needed to downgrade my laravel version and the tinker version in composer:json:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "algo-web/podata-laravel": "^0.3.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^5.8.9",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
```

The resulting routes:

```
/ GET|HEAD 
api/user GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|OPTIONS 
odata.svc GET|HEAD 
odata.svc/$metadata GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|OPTIONS
odata.svc/{section} GET|HEAD
```

It's possible to start the project and return a test value like a string or an empty view. But I can't access /odata.svc/Users. Does anynone maybe have a simple example how to use POData in laravel? Are there other php frameworks which implement ODATA.

Cheers

Comment: What is the output for `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: GET|HEAD/       GET|HEAD api/user         GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|OPTIONS  odata.svc                  
GET|HEAD   odata.svc/$metadata    GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|OPTIONS  odata.svc/{section}

Answer (score 0):

After removing the ConfirmPasswordController which didn't seem to be supported by the laravel version it works. Furthermore after assigning a new database and running php artisan cache:clear the database connection also works.